# the grid should display at least two columns , according to screen size can display more

Tags: android, gridview

I have GridView, the grid should display at least two columns , according to screen size can display more.

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_grid_gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="300dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

I don't know, how to do this.